# Regex bring just the match MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to getting just the first two words on sql query, I am using the match: `^\w{2}-` but with no success because nothing is coming to me, I need to get those values

BA, CE, DF, ES, GO, I don't know how can I do that, below some data example.

```
SC&Tipo=FM
SC&Tipo=Web
SC&Tipo=Comunitaria
RS&Tipo=Todas
RS&Tipo=AM
RS&Tipo=FM
RS&Tipo=Web
RS&Tipo=Comunitaria
BA-Salvador&Tipo=12horas
CE-Fortaleza&Tipo=12horas
CE-Interior&Tipo=12horas
DF-Brasilia&Tipo=12horas
ES-Interior&Tipo=12horas
ES-Vitoria&Tipo=12horas
GO-Goiania&Tipo=12horas
MG-ZonaDaMata/LestedeMinas&Tipo=12horas
MG-AltoParanaiba&Tipo=12horas
MG-BeloHorizonte&Tipo=12horas
MG-CentroOestedeMinas&Tipo=12horas
```

Query: `SELECT * FROM tabel WHERE filter REGEXP '^\w{2}-'`

## EDIT SOLVED:

To solve the query should be: 
`SELECT SUBSTRING(column, 1, 2) AS column FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]_]{2}-'`

Comment: Did you also try `SUBSTRING(<column>, 1, 2)` ?

Comment: But I need to match `^\w{2}-` it is not matching, am I doing something wrong on that?

Comment: No idea you didn't show the query..

Comment: Use `^[[:alnum:]_]{2}-`, or - if you need two uppercase letters, `^[[:upper:]]{2}_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support the character class `\w` or `\d`. Instead of `\w` you have to use `[[:alnum:]]`. You can find all the supported [character classes on the official MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html).

So you can use the following solution using [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE filter REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]{2}-'
```

You can use the following to get the result with regular expression too, using [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(filter, '^[[:alnum:]]{2}-') 
FROM table_name 
WHERE filter REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]{2}-';
```

Or another solution using `HAVING` to filter the result:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(filter, '^[[:alnum:]]{2}-') AS colResult 
FROM table_name 
HAVING colResult IS NOT NULL;
```

To get the value before MySQL 8.0 you can use the following with `LEFT`:

```
SELECT LEFT(filter, 3) 
FROM table_name 
WHERE filter REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]{2}-';
```

> **demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7mJEmCkEiYhCYK3PcEZTNE/0

Comment: If I merge both answer, the result will be there!! haha, SELECT SUBSTRING(column, 1, 2) AS column FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]_]{2}-' works perfectly, thank you!!!!

Comment: @OracyMartos you better off not merging both answers it means double processing is required.. if you use `SUBSTRING(<column>, 1, 2) ` in the `SELECT` and `WHERE` it will be processed once and cached in MySQL for the same record meaning you save valuabe CPU cycles on many records..

Answer (score 1):

Using `SUBSTRING(<column>, 1, 2)` should also work..

More or less like below

```
SELECT 
   <column>
 , SUBSTRING(<column>, 1, 2) 
FROM
 <table>
WHERE 
 SUBSTRING(<column>, 1, 2) IN ('BA' [,<value>..])
```

Some things are BNF (Backus-Naur form) in the SQL code.

`<..>` means replace with what you need. 
`[, ..]` means optional unlimited repeat the comma in there is part off SQL syntax

Comment: If I merge both answer, the result will be there!! haha, `SELECT SUBSTRING(column, 1, 2) AS column FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]_]{2}-'` works perfectly, thank you!!!!

Comment: OracyMartos you better off not merging both answers it means double processing is required.. if you use `SUBSTRING(<column>, 1, 2)` in the `SELECT` and `WHERE` it will be processed once and cached in MySQL for the same record meaning you save valuabe CPU cycles on many records.

Comment: *I need to get those values* - not working with `SUBSTRING`. You need to know the list for `IN` to get these values. You forgot one in this list, a record is missing.